# How do I apply a shell command to many files in nested (and poorly escaped) subdirectories?

Tags: bash, shell, find, for-loop, escaping

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
for file in `find . *.foo`
do
somecommand $file
done
```

But the command isn't working because $file is very odd.  Because my directory tree has crappy file names (including spaces), I need to escape the `find` command.  But none of the obvious escapes seem to work: 
  `-ls` gives me the space-delimited filename fragments
  `-fprint` doesn't do any better.

I also tried:  `for file in "`find . *.foo -ls`"; do echo $file; done
- but that gives all of the responses from find in one long line.`

Any hints?  I'm happy for any workaround, but am frustrated that I can't figure this out.

Thanks,
Alex

(Hi Matt!)

Comment: I am assuming you meant 'find . -name "*.foo"'? Otherwise 'find . *.foo' is probably going to give you strange results...

Comment: How can I do this with a for loop?  I'd like to extract some of the file name in a couple of different ways - presumably this is doable with a (very) long one-liner, but I'd prefer something more legible if possible.

Comment: Honestly, I'd probably try doing this in perl instead ;-)

Answer (score 11):

You have plenty of answers that explain well how to do it; but for the sake of completion I'll repeat and add to it:

`xargs` is only ever useful for interactive use (when you know all your filenames are plain - no spaces or quotes) or when used with the `-0` option.  Otherwise, it'll break everything.

`find` is a very useful tool; put using it to pipe filenames into `xargs` (even with `-0`) is rather convoluted as `find` can do it all itself with either `-exec command {} \;` or `-exec command {} +` depending on what you want:

```
find /path -name 'pattern' -exec somecommand {} \;
find /path -name 'pattern' -exec somecommand {} +
```

The former runs `somecommand` with **one argument** for each file recursively in `/path` that matches `pattern`.

The latter runs `somecommand` with **as many arguments as fit on the command line** at once for files recursively in `/path` that match `pattern`.

Which one to use depends on `somecommand`.  If it can take multiple filename arguments (like `rm`, `grep`, etc.) then the latter option is faster (since you run `somecommand` far less often).  If `somecommand` takes only one argument then you need the former solution.  So look at `somecommand`'s man page.

More on `find`: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

In `bash`, `for` is a statement that iterates over **arguments**.  If you do something like this:

```
for foo in "$bar"
```

you're giving `for` **one** argument to iterate over (note the quotes!).  If you do something like this:

```
for foo in $bar
```

you're asking `bash` to take the contents of `bar` and tear it apart wherever there are spaces, tabs or newlines (technically, whatever characters are in `IFS`) and use the pieces of that operation as arguments to for.  **That is NOT filenames**.  Assuming that the result of a tearing long string that contains filenames apart wherever there is whitespace yields in a pile of filenames is just wrong.  As you have just noticed.

The answer is: Don't use `for`, it's obviously the wrong tool.  The above `find` commands all assume that `somecommand` is an executable in `PATH`.  If it's a `bash` statement, you'll need this construct instead (iterates over `find`'s output, like you tried, but safely):

```
while read -r -d ''; do
    somebashstatement "$REPLY"
done < <(find /path -name 'pattern' -print0)
```

This uses a `while-read` loop that reads parts of the string `find` outputs until it reaches a `NULL` byte (which is what `-print0` uses to separate the filenames).  Since `NULL` bytes can't be part of filenames (unlike spaces, tabs and newlines) this is a safe operation.

If you don't need `somebashstatement` to be part of your script (eg. it doesn't change the script environment by keeping a counter or setting a variable or some such) then you can still use `find`'s `-exec` to run your `bash` statement:

```
find /path -name 'pattern' -exec bash -c 'somebashstatement "$1"' -- {} \;
find /path -name 'pattern' -exec bash -c 'for file; do somebashstatement "$file"; done' -- {} +
```

Here, the `-exec` executes a `bash` command with three or more arguments.

1. The bash statement to execute.
2. A `--`.  `bash` will put this in `$0`, you can put anything you like here, really.
3. Your filename or filenames (depending on whether you used `{} \;` or `{} +` respectively).  The filename(s) end(s) up in `$1` (and `$2`, `$3`, ... if there's more than one, of course).

The `bash` statement in the first `find` command here runs `somebashstatement` with the filename as argument.

The `bash` statement in the second `find` command here runs a `for`(**!**) loop that iterates over each positional parameter (that's what the reduced `for` syntax - `for foo; do` - does) and runs a `somebashstatement` with the filename as argument.  The difference here between the very first `find` statement I showed with `-exec {} +` is that we run only one `bash` process for lots of filenames but still one `somebashstatement` for **each** of those filenames.

All this is also well explained in the `UsingFind` page linked above.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of relying on the shell to do that work, rely on find to do it:

```
find . -name "*.foo" -exec somecommand "{}" \;
```

Then the file name will be properly escaped, and never interpreted by the shell.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name '*.foo' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 somecommand
```

It does get messy if you need to run a number of shell commands on each item, though.

Comment: Actually, you need -r (and hence GNU find or similar) to exactly emulate the for loop. xargs will otherwise execute the command with no arguments if the input is 0-length.

Comment: or you could use find's -exec {} + to avoid the convolution: find . -name '*.foo' -exec somecommand {} \;

Answer (score 1):

[xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) is your friend.  You will also want to investigate the -0 (zero) option with it.  `find` (with `-print0`) will help to produce the list.  The Wikipedia page has some good examples.

Another useful reason to use `xargs`, is that if you have many files (dozens or more), xargs will split them up into individual calls to whatever xargs is then called upon to run (in the first wikipedia example, `rm`)

Comment: "xargs will split them up into individual calls". Or if this isn't desirable, as happens in rare cases, then use "-n1 -r" to get the same behaviour as the for loop. -r is a GNU extension, -n is POSIX.

Comment: -1 because xargs is broken unless used with the -0 option and using the -0 option with find is pretty silly seeing as find itself has a -exec {} + predicate that does exactly the same thing.

Comment: '-0 |xargs' is easier to remember than escaping the call to '-exec {}' however, which can get complicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name '*.foo' -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c 'for F in "${@}"; do ...; done' "${0}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar some time ago, renaming files to allow them to live in Win32 environments:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
function RecurseDirs
{
for f in "$@"
do
  newf=echo "${f}" | sed -e 's/[\\/:\*\?#"\|<>]/_/g'
  if [ ${newf} != ${f} ]; then
    echo "${f}" "${newf}"
    mv "${f}" "${newf}"
    f="${newf}"
  fi
  if [[ -d "${f}" ]]; then
    cd "${f}"
    RecurseDirs $(ls -1 ".")
  fi
done
cd ..
}
RecurseDirs .
```

This is probably a little simplistic, doesn't avoid name collisions, and I'm sure it could be done better -- but this does remove the need to use basename on the find results (in my case) before performing my sed replacement.

I might ask, what are you doing to the found files, exactly?