# How to create soft-links for every file in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have a directory, `/original`, that has hundreds of files.  I have a script that will process files one at a time and delete the file so it's not executed again if the script gets interrupted.  So, I need a bunch of soft links to the files on `/original` to `/processing`.  Here's what I tried:

```
find /original -name "*.processme" -exec echo ln -s {} $(basename {}) \;
```

and got something like:

```
ln -s /original/1.processme /original/1.processme
ln -s /original/2.processme /original/2.processme
ln -s /original/3.processme /original/3.processme
...
```

I wanted something like:

```
ln -s /original/1.processme 1.processme
ln -s /original/2.processme 2.processme
ln -s /original/3.processme 3.processme
...
```

It appears that `$(basename)` is running before `{}` is converted.  Is there a way to fix that?  If not, how else could I reach my goal?

Comment: `basename` is run only once; see for an explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793892/recursively-rename-files-using-find-and-sed/4794313#4794313

Answer (score 16):

You can also use `cp` (specifically the `-s` option, which creates symlinks), eg.

```
find /original -name "*.processme" -print0 | xargs -0 cp -s --target-directory=.
```

Comment: This is the best recommendation at this time as using xargs instead of find with -exec is far more optimal.

Answer (score 6):

`find /original -name '*.processme' -exec echo ln -s {} . \;`

Special thanks to Ryan Oberoi for helping me realize that I can use a `.` instead of `$(basename ...)`.

Comment: Should be `'*.processme'` (single quotes) so that you do not match any files left over in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

How about -

```
ln -s $(echo /original/*.processme) .
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
find /original -name "*.processme" -exec sh -c 'echo ln -s "$@" $(basename "$@")' _ {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

you simply need to remove echo and strip the repeat of the filepath and basename entirely

If your Source folder is this

```
ls -l /original
total 3
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   345 Dec 17 21:17 1.processme
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   345 Dec 17 21:17 2.processme
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   345 Dec 17 21:17 3.processme
```

Then

```
cd /processing
find /original -name "*.processme" -exec ln -s '{}' \;
```

Should Produce

```
ls -l /processing
total 3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 33 Dec 17 21:38 1.processme -> /original/1.processme
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 33 Dec 17 21:38 2.processme -> /original/2.processme
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 33 Dec 17 21:38 3.processme -> /original/3.processme
```

Aware the OP is from 5 years ago I post this for those seeking the same solution like myself before I worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

`ls /home/mindon/bin/* | xargs ln -s -t /usr/local/bin/`