# Commandline find, sed, exec

Tags: bash, scripting, find, exec

I have a bunch of files in a folder, in subfolders and I'm trying to make some kind of one-liner for quick copy/pasting once in a while.

The contents is (too long to paste here): http://pastebin.com/4aZCPbwT

I've tried the following commands:

List all files and their directories

`find . -name '[!.]*'`

Replace all instances of "Namespace" with "Test:

`find . -name '[!.]*' -print0 | sed 's/Namespace/Test/gI' | xargs -i -0 echo '{}'`

What I need to do is:

Replace foldes names like above, and copy the folders (including files), to another location. Create the folders if they don't exist (they most likely won't) - BUT, there are some of them that I don't need, like ./app, as this folder exists. I could use -wholename './app' for that.

When they are copied, I need to replace some text inside each file, same as above (Namespace with Test - also occours inside the files and save them of course).

Something like this I would imagine:

`-print -exec sed -i 's/Namespace/Test/gI' {} \;`

Can these 3 things be done in a one-liner? Replace text in files (Namespace <=> Test), copy files including their directories with cp -p (don't want to write over folders), but renaming each directory/file with as above (Namespace <=> Test).

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Why wasting time to come up with one liner... I would just write a simple bash script with `for` loop or even better a `python` script. This can be nicely done in `python` interactive shell too.

Comment: Well, good point. Just seemed like it would be easier to just copy/paste something into my terminal :-). My Bash skills aren't that strong, so I probably wouldn't be able to write up a full script. I can only do small random commands.

Comment: The commands you posted show that you have some skill though:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides **describing the *how* with painstaking verbosity** below, this method may also be unique in that it incorporates built-in debugging. It basically doesn't do anything at all as written except compile and save to a variable all commands it believes it should do in order to perform the work requested.

It also explicitly **avoids loops** as much as possible. Besides the `sed` recursive search for more than one match of the *pattern* there is no other recursion as far as I know.

And last, this is entirely `null` delimited - it doesn't trip on any character in any filename except the `null`. I don't think you should have that.

By the way, this is *REALLY* fast. Look:

```
% _mvnfind() { mv -n "${1}" "${2}" && cd "${2}"
> read -r SED <<SED
> :;s|${3}\(.*/[^/]*${5}\)|${4}\1|;t;:;s|\(${5}.*\)${3}|\1${4}|;t;s|^[0-9]*\(.*\)${5}|\1|p
> SED
> find . -name "*${3}*" -printf "%d\tmv %P ${5} %P\000" |
> sort -zg | sed -nz ${SED} | read -r ${6}
> echo <<EOF
> Prepared commands saved in variable: ${6}
> To view do: printf ${6} | tr "\000" "\n"
> To run do: sh <<EORUN
> $(printf ${6} | tr "\000" "\n")
> EORUN
> EOF
> }
% rm -rf "${UNNECESSARY:=/any/dirs/you/dont/want/moved}"
% time ( _mvnfind ${SRC=./test_tree} ${TGT=./mv_tree} \
> ${OLD=google} ${NEW=replacement_word} ${sed_sep=SsEeDd} \
> ${sh_io:=sh_io} ; printf %b\\000 "${sh_io}" | tr "\000" "\n" \
> | wc - ; echo ${sh_io} | tr "\000" "\n" |  tail -n 2 )

   <actual process time used:>
    0.06s user 0.03s system 106% cpu 0.090 total

   <output from wc:>

    Lines  Words  Bytes
    115     362   20691 -

    <output from tail:>

    mv .config/replacement_word-chrome-beta/Default/.../googlestars \
    .config/replacement_word-chrome-beta/Default/.../replacement_wordstars
```

**NOTE:** The above `function` will likely require `GNU` versions of `sed` and `find` to properly handle the `find printf` and `sed -z -e` and `:;recursive regex test;t` calls. If these are not available to you the functionality can likely be duplicated with a few minor adjustments.

This should do everything you wanted from start to finish with very little fuss. I did `fork` with `sed`, but I was also practicing some `sed` recursive branching techniques so that's why I'm here. It's kind of like getting a discount haircut at a barber school, I guess. Here's the workflow:

- `rm -rf ${UNNECESSARY}`

  - I intentionally left out any functional call that might delete or destroy data of any kind. You mention that `./app` might be unwanted. Delete it or move it elsewhere beforehand, or, alternatively, you could build in a `\( -path PATTERN -exec rm -rf \{\} \)` routine to `find` to do it programmatically, but that one's all yours.
- `_mvnfind "${@}"`

  - Declare its arguments and call the worker function. `${sh_io}` is especially important in that it saves the return from the function. `${sed_sep}` comes in a close second; this is an arbitrary string used to reference `sed`'s recursion in the function. If `${sed_sep}` is set to a value that could potentially be found in any of your path- or file-names acted upon... well, just don't let it be.
- `mv -n $1 $2`

  - The whole tree is moved from the beginning. It will save a lot of headache; believe me. The rest of what you want to do - the renaming - is simply a matter of filesystem metadata. If you were, for instance, moving this from one drive to another, or across filesystem boundaries of any kind, you're better off doing so at once with one command. It's also safer. Note the `-noclobber` option set for `mv`; as written, this function will not put `${SRC_DIR}` where a `${TGT_DIR}` already exists.
- `read -R SED <<HEREDOC`

  - I located all of sed's commands here to save on escaping hassles and read them into a variable to feed to sed below. Explanation below.
- `find . -name ${OLD} -printf`

  - We begin the `find` process. With `find` we search only for anything that needs renaming because we already did all of the place-to-place `mv` operations with the function's first command. Rather than take any direct action with `find`, like an `exec` call, for instance, we instead use it to build out the command-line dynamically with `-printf`.
- `%dir-depth :tab: 'mv '%path-to-${SRC}' '${sed_sep}'%path-again :null delimiter:'`

  - After `find` locates the files we need it directly builds and prints out (*most*) of the command we'll need to process your renaming. The `%dir-depth` tacked onto the beginning of each line will help to ensure we're not trying to rename a file or directory in the tree with a parent object that has yet to be renamed. `find` uses all sorts of optimization techniques to walk your filesystem tree and it is not a sure thing that it will return the data we need in a safe-for-operations order. This is why we next...
- `sort -general-numerical -zero-delimited`

  - We sort all of `find`'s output based on `%directory-depth` so that the paths nearest in relationship to ${SRC} are worked first. This avoids possible errors involving `mv`ing files into non-existent locations, and it minimizes need to for recursive looping. (*in fact, you might be hard-pressed to find a loop at all*)
- `sed -ex :rcrs;srch|(save${sep}*til)${OLD}|\saved${SUBSTNEW}|;til ${OLD=0}`

  - I think this is the only loop in the whole script, and it only loops over the second `%Path` printed for each string in case it contains more than one ${OLD} value that might need replacing. All other solutions I imagined involved a second `sed` process, and while a short loop may not be desirable, certainly it beats spawning and forking an entire process.
  - So basically what `sed` does here is search for ${sed_sep}, then, having found it, saves it and all characters it encounters until it finds ${OLD}, which it then replaces with ${NEW}. It then heads back to ${sed_sep} and looks again for ${OLD}, in case it occurs more than once in the string. If it is not found, it prints the modified string to `stdout` (which it then catches again next) and ends the loop.
  - This avoids having to parse the entire string, and ensures that the first half of the `mv` command string, which needs to include ${OLD} of course, does include it, and the second half is altered as many times as is necessary to wipe the ${OLD} name from `mv`'s destination path.
- `sed -ex...-ex search|%dir_depth(save*)${sed_sep}|(only_saved)|out`

  - The two `-exec` calls here happen without a second `fork`. In the first, as we've seen, we modify the `mv` command as supplied by `find`'s `-printf` function command as necessary to properly alter all references of ${OLD} to ${NEW}, but in order to do so we had to use some arbitrary reference points which should not be included in the final output. So once `sed` finishes all it needs to do, we instruct it to wipe out its reference points from the hold-buffer before passing it along.

***AND NOW WE'RE BACK AROUND***

`read` will receive a command that looks like this:

```
% mv /path2/$SRC/$OLD_DIR/$OLD_FILE /same/path_w/$NEW_DIR/$NEW_FILE \000
```

It will `read` it into `${msg}` as `${sh_io}` which can be examined at will outside of the function.

Cool.

-Mike

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think it's what you're after.

```
find . -name '[!.]*' -print | while read line; do nfile=`echo "$line" | sed 's/Namespace/Test/gI'`; mkdir -p "`dirname $nfile`"; cp -p "$line" "$nfile"; sed -i 's/Namespace/Test/gI' "$nfile"; done
```