# Rename multiple files in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have multiple files in a directory, example: `linux_file1.mp4`, `linux_file2.mp4` and so on. How do I move these files, using shell, so that the names are `file1.mp4`, `file2.mp4` and so on. I have about 30 files that I want to move to the new name.

Comment: Related question: [Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25597051/2654678).

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I like [mmv](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/stable/en/man1/mmv.1.html) for this kind of thing

```
mmv 'linux_*' '#1'
```

But you can also use `rename`. Be aware that there are commonly two `rename` commands with very different syntax. One is written in Perl, the other is distributed with util-linux, so I distinguish them as "perl rename" and "util rename" below.

With Perl rename:

```
rename 's/^linux_//' linux_*.mp4
```

As cweiske correctly pointed out.

With util rename:

```
rename linux_ '' linux_*.mp4
```

How can you tell which rename you have? Try running `rename -V`; if your version is util rename it will print the version number and if it is perl rename it will harmlessly report and unknown option and show usage.

If you don't have either `rename` or `mmv` and don't want to or can't install them you can still accomplish this with plain old shell code:

```
for file in linux_*.mp4 ; do mv "$file" "${file#linux_}" ; done
```

This syntax will work with any POSIX sh conforming to XPG4 or later, which is essentially all shells these days.

Comment: The link provided is 404.

Comment: Can you explain this syntax: ${file#linux_}, I have a similar situation except I want to change *_32.png to *_24.png

Comment: @catalyst294: Shell variables can be expanded with `$foo` or `${foo}` (these are equivalent), and this is called parameter expansion, but the version with curly braces allows for modification of the value at the time of expansion, and this is called [parameter substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02). The [bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) implementation includes substitutions not required by the standard. Please remember to **always full-quote your variable expansions**, or suffer unexpected results!

Comment: What package usually provides `mmv`?

Comment: @AlexejMagura: Debian provides it in a package also named `mmv`. I cannot comment on other distributions.

Comment: Thank you for `rename` (which was already installed on Slackware) and the explanation about the name clash! `man rename` was also helpful.

Answer (score 18):

```
$ rename 's/linux_//' linux_*.mp4
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple native way to do it, with **directory traversal**:

```
find -type f | xargs -I {} mv {} {}.txt
```

Will rename every file in place adding extension .txt at the end.

And a more general cool way with **parallelization**:

```
find -name "file*.p" | parallel 'f="{}" ; mv -- {} ${f:0:10}trump${f:4}'
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to achieve replace filenames within directories by combining @dtrckd and @Sorpigal answers.

```
for file in `find -name "linux_*.mp4"`; do mv "$file" "${file/linux_/}" ; done
```