# Rename file names from zip in php

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

I have created zip files using shell_exec function. I am trying to rename files from created zip using shell_exec function. Any idea about it?

Comment: From the documentation: `shell_exec — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string`... just use the server to rename it. Linux and Windows rename commands will differ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename multiple files shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911301/rename-multiple-files-shell)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't using php built in rename() function?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Comment: dont wants to change actual file names

Answer (score 0):

I have solved problem using following command
                        shell_exec('printf "@ old_file_name.pdf\n@=new_file_name.pdf\n" | zipnote -w '.$zip_name);

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

**Create zip file:**
shell_exec('zip -j myzip.zip old_file_name.pdf');

**Rename created zip file:**
shell_exec('printf "@ old_file_name.pdf\n@=new_file_name.pdf\n" | zipnote -w '.myzip.zip);