# How to rename several directories in all subfolders In Unix terminal

Tags: terminal, grep, pipeline, batch-rename

I have a main directory called like "**Experiment**", where I keep several subfolders like "**time_data**", then several subfolders "**bacterial_strain**"and in the end "**drug concentration**" that is written like "**0,5 mM**". So the final path is:

```
/Experiment/time_data/bacterial_strain/0,5 mM
```

I want to rename all the directories in all subdirectories from "0,5 mM" to "0,7 mM"

I tried to run several different pipelines as:

```
find . -type d | grep 0,5 | mv "0,5 mM/" "0,7 mM/"
```

or

```
grep -r "0,5 mM" "/path_to_Experiment_folder" | mv 0,5\ mM 0,7\ mM
```

But Terminal gives the same mistake:

```
mv: rename 0,5 mM to 0,7 mM: No such file or directory
```

Please, help me, how to change the pipeline in order to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ find . -type d -name 0,5\ mM -print | while read dir ; do mv -v "${dir}" "${dir/0,5/0,7}" ; done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
find . -depth -type d -name "0,5mM*" -exec mv {} 
Experiment/time_data/bacterial_strain/drug_concentration/0,7mM \;
```

Things worth noting:

1. I noted that your last subfolder name contains a space `0,5 mM`. `find` command using space and executing an `-exec mv` with space did not work for me. I am not sure why. For testing purpose I removed the space character and the above command works, also its a single like command which I just separated for visibility, I am sure that will be figured out, but nevertheless ;).
2. I have used the entire path to rename the last file `0,5mM`. I supposed all your directories depths are the same, if not then you can probably explore the `-depth` option a little further.
3. If you have different depths directories or different names to rename, you can also encapsulate the above command in a script and run it on the parent directory.

I  hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
for f in Experiment/*/*/0,5\ mM; do nf=$(dirname "$f")/0,7\ mM; mv "$f" "$nf"; done
```

or (if you have also files with '0,5 mM' name which you do not want to rename):

```
for f in Experiment/*/*/0,5\ mM; do if [ -d "$f" ]; then nf=$(dirname "$f")/0,7\ mM; mv "$f" "$nf"; fi; done
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6912021/3218702) you can find other ways to do this.