# renaming files with bash, command clarification

Tags: bash, find

Following this questionn [Recursively rename files using find and sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793892/recursively-rename-files-using-find-and-sed/7783647#7783647) I found by myself this solution to rename files using find, but I can not fully understand the last part

```
find . -name '*_test.rb' -exec bash -c 'echo mv $1 ${1/test.rb/spec.rb}' _ {} \;
```

Can anyone explain the meaning of characters '_ {}',? I guess that is some sort arguments mapping from enviroments, but ...

Some clarification will be welcome.

Comment: Your quotes do not match. Could you double-check that this is the actual command?

Comment: I think '*_test.rb" should be '*_test.rb'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-exec command ;
```

The string `{}' is replaced by the current file name being processed. 
Consider the following:

```
% find . -type f
./file1
./file2
./file3
./file4
./file5
% find . -type f -exec sh -c 'printf "arg -> %s\n" "$0"' {} \;
arg -> ./file1
arg -> ./file2
arg -> ./file3
arg -> ./file4
arg -> ./file5
```

But here we execute `sh -c ...` for every single file found.
Note also that the filename is passed to the shell as *$0* (not *$1*).

If we wnat to optimize the code, as long as our command accepts more than one argument at a time for processing, we could use something like this:

```
% find . -type f -exec sh -c 'printf "arg -> %s\n" "$@"' {} +
arg -> ./file2
arg -> ./file3
arg -> ./file4
arg -> ./file5
```

Note the {} + syntax (vs. {} \;). From *find* man pages:

> ```
> -exec command {} +
>           This variant of the -exec action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the command line
>           is built by appending each selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of  the  com-
>           mand  will  be  much less than the number of matched files.  The command line is built in much the same
>           way that xargs builds its command lines.
> ```

But as you observe, the first file is missing (because *$@* contains all parameters except $0). That's why we need to set our $0 by hand, in order to process all arguments correctly:

```
% find . -type f -exec sh -c 'printf "arg -> %s\n" "$@"' put_whatever_you_want_here {} +
arg -> ./file1
arg -> ./file2
arg -> ./file3
arg -> ./file4
arg -> ./file5
```

In some situations you may need to set *$0* to something meaningful.

Comment: Can you expand upon the reason for using $1 and not just `find . -name '*_test.rb' -exec bash -c 'echo mv $0 ${0/test.rb/spec.rb}' {} \;`, please?

Comment: Hi @agtb, for me there is no difference _in this case_. If you refer to *$0* inside the code executed by the invocation of the shell (*shell -c ...*), of course, you won't find what you expect ...