# how to rename a file and move from one s3 bucket to another

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am using this command but unable to rename and move a file from one s3 folder to another

I want to rename this file as well as move

Here anagaza.csv000 is the file I want to rename and move it to movedData folder with the name angaza.csv

Once I move the file I also want a more generic approach where instead of file name like anagaza.csv000 I could use wildcard like anaga*.* or "wildcard.csv*" something like that but my destination should have the name I choose to give which is angaza.csv

```
aws s3 --recursive mv 
s3://mygluecrawlerbucket/angaza_accounts/to_be_processed/anagaza.csv000   
s3://mygluecrawlerbucket/angaza_accounts/movedData/angaza.csv --profile default
```

Comment: What is the exact logic you would want to use when renaming/moving the object? That is, how does it go from `anagaza.csv000` to `angaza.csv`? Will it always just be a matter of removing `000` from the end, or will there be different naming formats? Also, why have you included `--recursive`?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate new object names with shell script (`mv` or `rename`) and after that rename in S3 with `s3 mv` one by one.
For renaming the name of objects, you need to write regex or somethig by yourself. For renaming with regex, [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809666/rename-files-using-regular-expression-in-linux) will help.

Here is sample.sh I used.

```
list_objects=$(aws s3 ls s3://oldbucket | awk '{print $4}')

for old_object_name in $list_objects; do
    new_object_name=$(...) # mv or rename
    aws s3 mv s3://oldbucket/$old_object_name s3://newbucket/$new_object_name
done
```