# Change filenames using bash script: Replace commas and whitespaces by underscores

Tags: regex, sed, replace, whitespace

My files are of the format

```
Country, City S1.txt
```

e.g.

```
USA, Los Angeles S1.txt
USA, San Francisco S3.txt
UK, Glouchester S4.txt
Argentina, Buenos Aires S7.txt
```

I wish to change them to

```
Country_City_S1.txt
```

e.g.

```
USA_Los_Angeles_S1.txt
USA_San_Franciso_S3.txt
UK_Glouchester_S4.txt
Argentina_Buenos_Aires_S7.txt
```

To remove the comma I use the following sed command:

```bash
sed -i 's/,//g'
```

To replace the whitespaces with underscore, I use the following sed command:

```bash
sed -i 's/ /_/g'
```

*Question*: Is there a way to combine the above two commands into one? Or is there a neater way to accomplish the above?

**Notes:**

1. I have changed the title of my original post to better reflect what I need to be done. I am sorry for any confusion caused as a result of the change.
2. I understand now what I need, which is a bash script and not *sed* to change filenames.
3. I thank all those who have replied with their suggested *sed* commands.
4. I prefer to use the *mv* command in a bash script as in for example
   *for f in *.txt; do mv .......; done*

Answer (score 1):

Replace any combination of spaces and commas with a single underscore:

```
sed -E 's/[, ]+/_/g'
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/0dbddF).

---

To rename files using this regex on *any* *nix OS (macos doesn't ship with `rename`):

```
for f in *.txt; do mv $f $(echo "$f" | sed -E 's/[, ]+/_/g'); done
```

If your *nix has the `rename` command (`brew install rename` if you're macos):

```
rename 's/[, ]+/_/g' *.txt
```

Comment: I have made some changes to my original post, including the title of the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Merge your two `sed` expressions:

```bash
sed 's/,//g; s/ /_/g'
```

Comment: Bonjour Arnaud. I have made some changes to my original post, including the title of the subject. I am sorry for the confusion caused to you.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/,//g;y/ /_/' file
```

Remove commas and translate spaces to underscores.

Or perhaps:

```
sed -E s/,? +/_/g' file
```

---

To rename file names, perhaps:

```
sed -E 'h;s/,? +//g;H;g;s/(.*)\n(.*)/mv "\1" "\2"/e' <<<"$filename"
```

Comment: I have made a terrible mistake in my original post. sed commands don't work on changing of filenames, do they?

Could you help with me a command that looks something like the following? for file in .......; do .......; done    [Thank you in advance]

Comment: @JoelT  changing filenames is best done using `rename` or `mv` . The `rename` command  uses perl see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809666/rename-files-using-regular-expression-in-linux).

Comment: I don't wish to use `rename`. In fact I was thinking of using `mv` as in `for f in *.txt; do mv .......; done` Can you help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried your tip on renaming filenames using `sed`. The error message is: *sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown option to `s'*

Comment: Per your advice, I first removed the `e` flag and ran your `sed` command again. I have the same error message.

Comment: I tried your solution again and the same error message appeared.

Comment: @JoelT. Hmm? See [here](https://www.ideone.com/WdC7My)

Answer (score 0):

One line solution here:

```bash
find *.txt | sed -E 'p;s/[, ]+/_/g' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n2 mv
```

This is a very useful command template for batch renaming files:

```bash
find ... | sed 'p;s/...' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n2 mv
```