# Rename files and directories recursively under ubuntu /bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, find

I want to rename all files and directories that contain the word "special" to "regular". It should maintain case sensitivity so "Special" won't become "regular".

How can i do this in bash recursively?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively rename files using find and sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793892/recursively-rename-files-using-find-and-sed)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Try doing this (require `bash --version` >= 4):

```
shopt -s globstar
rename -n 's/special/regular/' **
```

Remove the `-n` switch when your tests are OK

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

and not containing:

```
ELF
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://web.archive.org/web/20130625192518/https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Comment: what is the `shopt -s globstar` for?

Comment: It enables the bash feature `**` (stands for recursive) maybe already enabled.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24933/discussion-between-sputnick-and-tom)

Comment: The chat window you linked to is borked..I just try this and I got this response: 
rename: invalid option -- 'n'

version: [##@localhost Staticality]$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: I have about 1700 files to rename in directories in my home directory. That seems too many for this to work, that actually was the text in the error message, too many arguments.

Comment: @killjoy: you have to install perl's rename. (sometimes named `prename` or install the module: `cpan File::Rename`

@Dennis: use find : `find . -exec rename 's/special/regular/' {} +`

Comment: Does it work recursively in the current directory or globally? In other words,  is the path "." or "/"?

Comment: For me this causes `-bash: /usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long`

Comment: So use `find /dir -exec rename 's///' {} +`

Comment: You may have to run the rename command multiple times in a row: run it until it doesn't report moved files.

Comment: -_- Are you sure you have perl's rename before 'downvoting' ?

Comment: in order to avoid errors use for i in **; do rename 's/<toreplace>/<replacewith>/' "$i"; done after globstar

Comment: People trying to rename a pattern occuring multiple times in the same name should add the 'g' flag at the end of the substitution command: `'s/old/new/g'`

Answer (score 120):

A solution using `find`:

To rename *files only*:

```
find /your/target/path/ -type f -exec rename 's/special/regular/' '{}' \;
```

To rename *directories only*:

```
find /your/target/path/ -type d -execdir rename 's/special/regular/' '{}' \+
```

To rename both *files and directories*:

```
find /your/target/path/ -execdir rename 's/special/regular/' '{}' \+
```

Comment: @speakr, Great solution, thanks! Could you provide more details about what it is doing, especially this part " '{}' \ "? Quick goggling did not help, so I thought that this information may be useful for others as well.

Comment: @DmitryGonchar Just take a look at `-exec command ;` in the [_find_ manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

Comment: I tried this with the -n flag (not ready to experiment with permanet results yet, and got this error: Replacement list is longer than search list at (eval 1) line 1.
My actual command invoked was: find $HOME -type f -exec prename -n 'y/ /-_-/' '{}' \;

Comment: @ThiloSchulz It does, but you have to use `find … -execdir … '{}' +` instead of `… '{}' \;`. Clarification added.

Comment: @speakr I'm not getting the results I'm expecting for replacing directories, and I'm not sure I'm understanding the 'find ... -execdir suggestion. Do I change type f to type d? Can you please write out the full working command for directories in your answer please?

Comment: @user658182 Yes, use `-type d` combined with `-execdir` for directories only.

Comment: In case of many files, take advantage of regex in find, for the last example above you use: ``find /your/target/path/ -regex '.*special.*' -execdir rename 's/special/regular/' '{}' \+``, otherwise it will be quite slow!

Comment: great, thank you.  However, does not seem to do the job `recursively` on OSX....

Comment: this does not work when used "^" `Can't rename /mnt/B.JPG image_/mnt/B.JPG: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind installing another tool, then you can use [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm):

```
rnm -rs '/special/regular/g' -dp -1 *
```

It will go through all directories/sub-directories (because of `-dp -1`) and replace *special* with *regular* in their names.

Comment: Is this installed from Homebrew?

Comment: @LokMac : I don't think it's available in homebrew (I only package binary for debian based OS), If you have automake, you can install it in any Unix system (Instructions are in the [readme](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm/blob/release/README.md#install-from-source)).

Comment: Great tool! Worked for me!

Answer (score 7):

Here is another approach which is more portable and does **not** rely on the `rename` command (since it may require different parameters depending on the distros).

It renames files and directories recursively:

```
find . -depth -name "*special*" | \
while IFS= read -r ent; do mv $ent ${ent%special*}regular${ent##*special}; done
```

**What it does**

- use find with `-depth` parameter to reorder the results by performing a *depth-first traversal* (i.e. all entries in a directory are displayed before the directory itself).
- do pattern substitutions to only modifiy the last occurence of *regular* in the path.

That way the files are modified first and then each parent directory.

**Example**

Giving the following tree:

```
├── aa-special-aa
│   └── bb-special
│       ├── special-cc
│       ├── special-dd
│       └── Special-ee
└── special-00
```

It generate those `mv` commands in that particular order:

```
mv ./aa-special-aa/bb-special/special-cc ./aa-special-aa/bb-special/regular-cc
mv ./aa-special-aa/bb-special/special-dd ./aa-special-aa/bb-special/regular-dd
mv ./aa-special-aa/bb-special ./aa-special-aa/bb-regular
mv ./aa-special-aa ./aa-regular-aa
mv ./special-00 ./regular-00
```

To obtain the following tree:

```
├── aa-regular-aa
│   └── bb-regular
│       ├── regular-cc
│       ├── regular-dd
│       └── Special-ee
└── regular-00
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation, perfect fit my needs.

Answer (score 6):

[@speakr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012788/1541330) was the clue for me.

If using -execdir to transform both files and directories, you'll also want to remove `-type f` from the example shown. To spell it out, use:

`find /your/target/path/ -execdir rename 's/special/regular/' '{}' \+`

Also, consider adding `g` (global) flag to the regex if you want to replace **all** occurrences of `special` with `regular` in a given filename and not just the first occurrence. For example:

`find /your/target/path/ -execdir rename 's/special/regular/g' '{}' \+`

will transform `special-special.jpg` to `regular-regular.jpg`. Without the global flag, you'll end up with `regular-special.jpg`.

FYI: GNU Rename is not installed by default on Mac OSX.  If you are using the [Homebrew package manager](https://brew.sh/), `brew install rename` will remedy this.

Comment: will this correclty handle including folders? e.g. `/special/regular/regular-specilal.jpeg`

Comment: Yes, it will rename both files and folders.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Rui Seixas Monteiro it's best to use the -iregex pattern option with the Find command. I've found the following works and includes the global flag in the regex as mentioned by U007D:

Files:

```
find /path/ -type f -iregex '.*special.*' -execdir rename 's/special/regular/g' '{}' \+;
```

Directories:

```
find /path/ -type d -iregex '.*special.*' -execdir rename 's/special/regular/g' '{}' \+;
```

Files and Directories

```
find /path/ -iregex '.*special.*' -execdir rename 's/special/regular/g' '{}' \+;
```

Comment: But it doesn't do a depth first traversal so it's open to problems with parent directories haven't been renamed first.

Answer (score 2):

For those just wanting to rename directories you can use this command:

```
find /your/target/path/ -type d -execdir rename 's/special/regular/' '{}' \;
```

Note type is now `d` for directory, and using `-execdir`.

I haven't been able to work out how to rename both files and directories in a single pass though.

Someone commented earlier that once it renamed the root folder then it couldn't traverse the file tree any more.  There is a `-d` switch available that does a depth traversal from the bottom-up, so the root would be renamed last I believe:

```
find -d /your/target/path/ -type d -execdir rename 's/special/regular/' '{}' \;
```

From the manpage (`man find`):

```
 -d      Cause find to perform a depth-first traversal, i.e., directories are visited in post-order and all entries in a directory will be
         acted on before the directory itself.  By default, find visits directories in pre-order, i.e., before their contents.  Note, the
         default is not a breadth-first traversal.
```

Comment: If anyone can clarify what is done to action the command for both files and directories in a single pass that would be appreciated too, and I'll update this answer with the command.

Answer (score 1):

For `rename` version `rename from util-linux 2.23.2` the following command worked for me:

`find . -type f -exec rename mariadb mariadb-proxy '{}' \;`