# rename folder/directory recursively

Tags: bash, exec, rename

I want to rename folder/directory names recursively and found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012631/rename-files-and-directories-recursively-under-ubuntu-bash) on SO. However this command has no effect

```
find . -type f -exec rename 's/old/new/' '{}' \;
```

Is that a correct command?

Comment: `f` is for files. `d` for directories (folders isn't a common term for that in Unix-y context)

Comment: Does running the find _without_ the exec part do anything?

Comment: One way to check whether or not your shell script will work is to echo the command. So for example: (note that {} is not in '')

`find . -type d -exec echo rename 's/a_/b_/' '{}' \;`

Does the output look like what you expect? If so pipe it to shell :P

Comment: could just use a loop instead `for f in $( find . -type f -name "*a*" ); do mv $f $(basename $f | sed "s/a/b/") ; done`

Comment: @Jidder: Still no effect. Have you test that?

Comment: Yep, works for me ? What problem are you having with it ? Is there an error ?

Comment: `for f in $( find . -type f -name "*b_*" ); do mv $f $( dirname $f)/$(basename $f | sed "s/b_/a_/") ; done` forgot to leave the original directory there. That should work recursively now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -depth -name '*a_*' -execdir bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0//a_/b_}"' {} \;
```

The `-depth` switch is important so that the directory content is processed before the directory itself! otherwise you'll run into problems `:)`.

100% safe regarding filenames with spaces or other funny symbols.

Comment: Yup. That is a simpler solution. I will clean the original post