# Using 'rename' command for all files in subfolders

Tags: replace, command-line, rename, putty, batch-rename

I am using this command to replace a word with another in many filenames (batch):

```
rename 's/oldname/newname/g' **
```

But it works for the current open folder only.  I am not sure how to make it work for that directory and all the sub-directories.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mike,
Try this: Create new folders, move files, delete old folder. Then, move over directories.
Regards

Comment: Can you provide the command needed to accomplish this in a batch

Comment: See this article:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012631/rename-files-and-directories-recursively-under-ubuntu-bash

Comment: Try doing this (require bash --version >= 4):

shopt -s globstar
rename -n 's/special/regular/' **

Remove the -n switch when your tests are OK