# Rename recursively repository and file names by replacing a pattern by another

Tags: bash, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I'd like to recursively rename all repository and file names under a specific directory that contain a given pattern.

I think I found a potential solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012788/8838180) with the following command:

```
find /your/target/path/ -execdir rename 's/special/regular/' '{}' \+
```

However it seems like I don't have the right `rename` command.

I installed Perl **Rename** package but I still don't have the Perl based `rename` command available. What can I do to be able to use this command?

Is there an alternative solution to this `rename` solution?

Let's say I have the following repositories and files:

```
BOOK1/
BOOK1/BOOK1_summary.txt
BOOK1/BOOK1_chapter1/BOOK1_chapter1.txt
```

I'd like to rename all occurrences of **BOOK1** by **BOOK-01** in repository and file names:

```
BOOK1-01/
BOOK1-01/BOOK1-01_summary.txt
BOOK1-01/BOOK1-01_chapter1/BOOK1-01_chapter1.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `rename` `PERL` utility which could be downloaded from [this](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) link.

```
find  BOOK1 -depth -exec rename -n 's/^(.*)(BOOK1)(.*)$/$1BOOK1-01$3/' {} \;
```

**Dry-run output**

```
rename(BOOK1/BOOK1_summary.txt, BOOK1/BOOK1-01_summary.txt)
rename(BOOK1/BOOK1_chapter1/BOOK1_chapter1.txt, BOOK1/BOOK1_chapter1/BOOK1-01_chapter1.txt)
rename(BOOK1/BOOK1_chapter1, BOOK1/BOOK1-01_chapter1)
rename(BOOK1, BOOK1-01)
```

Remove the `-n` option from `rename` once you verify the *dry-run* result..

**Actual Output**

```
 ls -R BOOK1-01/ # Used a recursive listing here.
BOOK1-01/:
BOOK1-01_chapter1  BOOK1-01_summary.txt

BOOK1-01/BOOK1-01_chapter1:
BOOK1-01_chapter1.txt
```

<sub>**Note :** The `-depth` option with find is the key here. The `find manpage` says it process each directory's contents before the directory itself.</sub>

Comment: the 'rename' command does not have the -n option on my side. I tried without it directly and it gave me the following error message: 'rename: not enough arguments'

Also, I saw that you used '3/s' at the end of the 'rename' command. I think it's because there are 3 occurrences max per path on my example right? If there is more, can I use '/g' instead?

Comment: It is not `3/s` It is `$3`. Please note that I have used three `(stuff)`. Anything inside the parenthesis `()` can be reused  using `$1` for the first match, `$2` for the second match and so. The global option `g` should NOT be used here as it is detrimental to this solution.

Comment: @thbtmntgn I have made a small change in the `find` command. Please try the new one. If you don't have the `-n` option search the man-page for `rename` and look for the option that gives you the `dry-run` option. There was a rogue `s` at the end of  `rename` script which I removed.  Try the new one and let me know if you got any luck with it :)

Comment: I re-run your command and got the "rename: not enough arguments" error. The 'rename' command I have does not seems to have a dry-run option. Only four options: 
-v/--verbose --> explain what is being done,
-s/--symlink --> act on symlink target,
-h/--help --> display this help and exit,
-V/--version --> output version information and exit

Comment: /usr/bin/rename: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.35

Comment: rename from util-linux 2.23.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191992/discussion-between-thbtmntgn-and-sjsam).

Comment: Installing 'File::Rename' Perl package with 'cpan' solved the problem for me. It created the 'rename' executable in '/usr/local/bin'