# how to rename folders recursively in linux

Tags: linux

I want to rename all the folders contained in a specific folder that starts with "Test" replacing by "Product".
Example:
In my main folder I have the following folders:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
....
```

that I want to rename them into:

```
Product1
Product2
Product3
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename files and directories recursively under ubuntu /bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012631/rename-files-and-directories-recursively-under-ubuntu-bash)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012631/rename-files-and-directories-recursively-under-ubuntu-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand correctly, you don't want to rename files "recursively", but you want to rename multiple files.

Maybe it is not the best possibility to do this, but I would do it like this:

```
for a in Test*; do mv $a `echo $a | sed -e s/Test/Products/`; done
```

Explanation:

```
for a in Test*; do <some command> ; done
```

This will perform some command for each file matching the pattern `Test*`. `$a` is the placeholder for the file name.

```
echo $a | sed -e s/Test/Products/
```

This command prints the file name while `Test` is replaced by `Products`. If the file name (`$a`) is `Test123`, the command will print `Products123`.

```
mv $a `<some command>`
```

This command renames the file `$a`. The new file name is the text that is printed by the command `<some command>`.

If you really want to perform the renaming recursively (in all sub-directories), you might use the `find` command:

```
for a in `find . | grep Test`; do ...
```

**EDIT**

> I want to rename the folders and not the files

A folder is some kind of "file" in Linux; what you call "file" is called "regular file" in Linux. And the commands above do not distinguish between folders and "regular files".

So if your parent folder does not contain any "regular file" (or symbolic link or pipe ...) matching the name pattern `Test*`, you can use the commands above.

If your parent folder contains both sub-folders and other types of files (for example "regular files" or symbolic links) that match the name pattern `Test*` and you only want to rename the sub-folders, you may use the `find` command to select all folders in the current parent folder:

```
for a in `find -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep /Test`; do ...
```

**Edit 2**

I didn't know the `rename` command mentioned in the answer linked in one of the comments to your question. And the `rename` tool seems not to be available in every Linux distribution.

Using `rename` you might do it the following way:

```
rename Test Product `find -maxdepth 1 -type d`
```

This will search for all sub-directories in the current directory and replace `Test` by `Product` in the name. The sub-directory named `MyTest5` becomes `MyProduct5`.

However, a regular file named `Test6` will not be renamed.

If you only want to rename directories whose name starts with `Test`, you may do it the following way:

```
rename Test Product `find -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep /Test`
```

`Test5` will become `Product5` but `MyTest5` will not be renamed.

Unfortunately, I haven't used the `rename` tool myself, so I'm not sure if this really works.

Comment: I want to rename the folders and not the files

Comment: @salconte Please see my two "Edit" sections.