# strip multiple dashes from filenames recursively

Tags: bash, rename

I want to strip filenames recursively that have multiple dashes, so that **file---name-3.jpg** becomes **file-name-3.jpg**.  This works fine within a single folder but I would like to move into the parent folder, and run the command.  It also works fine until it runs into a folder name that also has multiple dashes, and then it tries to rename them.

`find . -type f -iname '*---*' -depth -exec rename 's/---/-/gi' {} +`

```
parent_folder
  \sub--folder-1
     file--name-1.jpg <-- rename file-name-1.jpg
     file----name-2.jpg <-- rename file-name-2.jpg
  \sub----folder-2
     file--name-1.jpg <-- rename file-name-1.jpg
```

**edit** using bash on a CentOS server

Comment: You should tag your question with the language/shell you are using.

Comment: i remember doing that using sed to parse the final name, as you are using "-type f" and you have the full path name, take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793892/recursively-rename-files-using-find-and-sed

Answer (score 1):

Use -execdir to run the command from the file's directory with just the filename, rather than -exec which runs it from the current directory with relative path:

```
find . -depth -type f -iname '*---*' -execdir rename 's/---/-/gi' {} +
```