# change all word occurrences under each directory recursively

Tags: java, linux

Haw can I change a word after searching under some directory :
for example change the word ***abc*** to ***ddd*** located in all .c files.

```
grep --include=\*.c -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "abc"
```

Then how can I modify these occurrences to be ***ddd***? 
What is the command line?

Comment: And this is connected to Java how?

Comment: Take a look at the `sed` command: `man sed`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793892/recursively-rename-files-using-find-and-sed

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're on Linux... ok?

It's very simple:

```
find <directory> -type f -name \*.c -print0 | xargs -0 -t sed -i 's/abc/ddd/g'
```

The first part of the command will find all files with extension .c under "directory" (you will have to use the real directory name here (for example a single '.' (dot) to look into your current directory). Filenames with extension .c are then passed via `xargs` to `sed` that will replace "in-place" all occurrences of "abc" with "ddd". **Be aware**: this command will replace ALL "abc" to "ddd" ("abc" > "ddd", "abcdefg" > "ddddefg", etc...). If you want something different or study how these commands work:

```
man find
man xargs
man sed
```

Comment: i try this one on my root directory recursivly because i have multiple poms inside there.
'grep -r --include=pom.xml -e "1.2.0-SNAPSHOT"  | xargs -0 -t sed -i 's/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/g''
the out put show me all files that contains the 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT and show me message **File name too long**

Comment: @Feres_f Your command is wrong. Check xargs man page (option -0). It works if you have a find with -print0 in front of it...