# Rename directories, files and text recursively

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, batch-rename

I am trying to rename directories, files and text inside them recursively
I am using `rename` brew formula on macOS Sierra.

```
find . -type f -exec rename 's|{{ cookiecutter.name }}|QWERTYUIOPASDF|' * {} +
```

Here is the Dry Run with `-n` command

```
'{{ cookiecutter.name }}' would be renamed to 'QWERTYUIOPASDF'
'./{{ cookiecutter.name }}/Sources/{{ cookiecutter.name }}.h' would be renamed to './QWERTYUIOPASDF/Sources/{{ cookiecutter.name }}.h'
```

But in execution the root directory is renamed from `{{ cookiecutter.name }} to QWERTYUIOPASDF`

but for the subdirectories it shows

```
'./{{ cookiecutter.name }}/Sources/{{ cookiecutter.name }}.h' not renamed: './QWERTYUIOPASDF/Sources/{{ cookiecutter.name }}.h' already exists
```

obviously because it is trying to find

```
./{{ cookiecutter.name }}/Sources/{{ cookiecutter.name }}
```

which has now changed to

```
./QWERTYUIOPASDF/Sources/{{ cookiecutter.name }}
```

How can I fix this ?

And also how can I use `sed -i 's/{{ cookiecutter.name }}/QWERTYUIOPASDF/g'` to rename all text inside all files recursively

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793892/recursively-rename-files-using-find-and-sed

Comment: That answer don't work in this case.