# find -exec when used with sed for file rename not working

Tags: bash, unix, sed, terminal, zsh

I've been trying:

```
find dev-other -name '*.flac' -type f -exec echo $(echo {} | sed 's,^[^/]*/,,') \;
```

I expect to see a list of paths to `.flac` files within `dev-other`, but without a prepended `dev-other/`, e.g.:

```
4515/11057/4515-11057-0095.flac
4515/11057/4515-11057-0083.flac
4515/11057/4515-11057-0040.flac
4515/11057/4515-11057-0105.flac
4515/11057/4515-11057-0017.flac
4515/11057/4515-11057-0001.flac
```

Instead I see

```
dev-other/4515/11057/4515-11057-0095.flac
dev-other/4515/11057/4515-11057-0083.flac
dev-other/4515/11057/4515-11057-0040.flac
dev-other/4515/11057/4515-11057-0105.flac
dev-other/4515/11057/4515-11057-0017.flac
```

Why isn't the `sed` replace working here even though it works on its own

```
$ echo $(echo dev-other/4515/11057/4515-11057-0047.flac | sed 's,^[^/]*/,,')
4515/11057/4515-11057-0047.flac
```

---

I first tried with expansions:

```
find dev-other -name '*.flac' -type f -exec a={} echo ${a#*/} \;
```

But got the errors:

```
find: a=dev-other/700/122866/700-122866-0001.flac: No such file or directory
find: a=dev-other/700/122866/700-122866-0030.flac: No such file or directory
find: a=dev-other/700/122866/700-122866-0026.flac: No such file or directory
find: a=dev-other/700/122866/700-122866-0006.flac: No such file or directory
find: a=dev-other/700/122866/700-122866-0010.flac: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Interesting question, and the answer of why `sed` not work is probably here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793892/recursively-rename-files-using-find-and-sed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use parameter expansion for your use-case when using `find` with the `-exec` option,

```
find dev-other -name '*.flac' -type f -exec bash -c 'x=$1; y="${x#*/}"; echo "$y"' bash {} \;
```

I used a separate shell (use `bash` or `sh`) using `bash -c` because to involve separate string operations involving parameter expansion. Think of each output of `find` result to be passed as argument to this sub-shell where this manipulation takes place.

When `bash -c` executes a command, the next argument after the command is used as `$0` (the script's "name" in the process listing), and subsequent arguments become the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, etc.). This means that the filename passed by find (in place of the `{}`) becomes the first parameter of the script `--` and is referenced by `$1` inside the mini-script

If you don't want to use an extra `bash`, use `_` in-place

```
find dev-other -name '*.flac' -type f -exec bash -c 'x=$1; y="${x#*/}"; echo "$y"' _ {} \;
```

where `_` i is a `bash` predefined variable (not defined in `dash` for instance): "At shell startup, set to the absolute path-name used to invoke the shell or shell script being executed as passed in the environment or argument list" ( See [man bash - Special Parameters](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) section)

Worth looking at [Using Find - Complex Actions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Complex_actions)

Comment: Why not just `... -exec sh -c 'echo "${1#*/}"' sh {} \;` ? You don't need so many auxiliary variables...

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf : Yes but I’d argue using an extra variable, I could demonstrate how the output of find is being parsed inside the sub shell as $1 . It could be still be avoided though ;)