# SED: replace semvers of multiple files

Tags: regex, bash, sed, substitution

[**context**] My script needs to replace **semvers** of multiple `.car` names with **commit sha**. In short, I would like that every `dev_CA_1.0.0.car` became `dev_CA_6a8zt5d832.car`

ADDING **commit sha** right before `.car` was pretty trivial. With this, I end up with `dev_CA_1.0.0_6a8zt5d832.car`

```sh
find . -depth -name "*.car" -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; \
mv -- "$f" $(echo $f | sed -e 's/.car/_${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}.car/g')' \;
```

But I find it incredibly difficult to **REPLACE**. What aspect of `sed` am I misconceiving trying this:

```sh
find . -depth -name "*.car" -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; \
mv -- "$f" $(echo $f | sed -r -E 's/[0-9\.]+.car/${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}.car/g')
```

or this

```sh
find . -depth -name "*.car" -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; \
mv -- "$f" $(echo $f | sed -r -E 's/^(.*_)[0-9\.]+\.car/\1${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}\.car/g')' \;
no matches found: f="{}"; mv -- "$f" $(echo $f | sed -r -E ^(.*_)[0-9.]+.car/1684981321531.car/g)
```

or multiple variants:

- `\` escaping (e.g. `\\.`)
- `(` and `)` escaping (e.g. `\(`) (I read somewhere that regex grouping with `sed` requires some care with `()`)

Is there a more direct way to do it?

### Edit

`$f` getting in `sed` are path looking like

```
./somewhere/some_project_CA_1.2.3.car
./somewhere_else/other_project_CE_9.2.3.car
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
sed "s/_[0-9.]\{1,\}\.car$/_${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}.car/g"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/8nLcS1)

Here, `sed` is used with a POSIX ERE expression, that matches

- `_` - an underscore
- `[0-9.]\{1,\}` - 1 or more digits or dots
- `\.car` - `.car` (note that a literal `.` must be escaped! a `.` pattern matches any char)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Your answer / demo is clear but I am still getting the same error. I should have been more explicit about what is exactly piped in `sed` (see my edit). Maybe the problem is not `sed` *per se* but way I execute it

Comment: @zar3bski So, `./somewhere/some_project_CA.1.2.3.car` is your input? Then use `sed "s/\.[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}\.car$/_${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}.car/"`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/GH1TDF). Or `sed -E "s/\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.car$/_${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}.car/"`

Comment: Still the same so I think that `-exec sh -c` is messing with the instruction passed to `sed` (and with my brain: manes are actually `_1.0.7.car` not `.1.0.7.car`). I'll look for a more direct approach. Thanks for your instructing demos

Comment: @zar3bski Make sure you are using *double quoation marks* around the `sed` command, else, there won't be any variable expansion.

Comment: however, the value of `CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA` does not appear. I guess `-exec sh` does not inherit the variables from the shell that is calling him. But I can find a workarund (like looping with a `for`)

Comment: @zar3bski Also, check [Recursively rename files using find and sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4793892/3832970)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
export CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA=6a8zt5d832
find . -depth -name "*.car" -exec sh -c \
 'f="{}"; echo mv "$f" "${f%_*}_${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}.car"' \;
```

Remove `echo` once you are satisfied of the result.