# Rename files in Bash based upon a sed script or dictionary

Tags: bash, shell, sed, file-rename

In Bash, I wish to rename many files based upon a predefined dict with many replacement strings. I have multiple files nested in a directory tree, like:

```
./aa
./b/aa
./b/bb
./c/aa
./c/d/ee
```

I have a "sed script" `dict.sed` whose contents is like:

```
s|aa|xx|g
s|ee|yy|g
```

Can I recursively `find` and rename files matching aa and ee to xx and yy, respectively, and preserving the directory structure, using said sed script?

At the moment I have:

```
function rename_from_sed() {
    IFS='|' read -ra SEDCMD <<< "$1"
    find "." -type f -name "${SEDCMD[1]}" -execdir mv {} "${SEDCMD[2]}" ';'
}

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "${line}" ]]; do
    rename_from_sed "$line"
done < "dict.sed"
```

This seems to work, but is there a better way, perhaps using `sed -f dict.sed` instead of parsing `dict.sed` line-by-line? The current approach means I need to specify the delimiter, and is also limited to exact filenames.

The closest other answer is probably https://stackoverflow.com/a/11709995/3329384 but that also has the limitation that directories may also be renamed.

Answer (score 0):

That seems odd: iterating over the lines in a sed script. You want:

> Can I recursively find and rename files

So iterate over files, not over the sed script.

```
find .... | while IFS= read -r file; do
     newfile=$(sed -f dict.sed <<<"$file")
     mv "$file" "$newfile"
done
```

Related https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

> but is there a better way

Sure - do not use Bash and do use Sed. Write the whole script in Python or Perl - it will be 1000 times faster to use a tool which will do all the operations in a single thread without any `fork()` calls.

---

Anyway, you can also parse sed script line by line and run a single `find` call.

```
find "." -type f '(' -name aa -execdir mv {} xx ';' ')' -o '(' -name ee -execdir mv {} yy ';' ')'
```

You would have to build such call, like:

```
findargs=()
while IFS='|' read -r _ f t _; do
    if ((${#findargs[@]})); then findargs+=('-o'); fi
    findargs+=( '(' -name "$f" -execdir {} "$t" ';' ')' )
done < "dict.sed"
find . -type f "${findargs[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming lines in the file `dict` is in the form of `from|to`, below is an implementation in pure `bash`, without using `find` and `sed`.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar nullglob

while IFS='|' read -r from to; do
    for path in ./**/*"$from"*; do
        [[ -f $path ]] || continue
        basename=${path##*/}
        echo mv "$path" "${path%/*}/${basename//"$from"/"$to"}"
    done
done < dict
```

--

```
$ cat dict
aa|xx
ee|yy
```

Drop the `echo` if you are satisfied with the output.