# How to find all files in all subdirectories using for in linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I apply a shell command to many files in nested (and poorly escaped) subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753823/how-do-i-apply-a-shell-command-to-many-files-in-nested-and-poorly-escaped-subd)

I am using this loop to remove empty lines in all files under given directories and sub directories. But it is not working

```
for file in /home/zubinan/public_html/src/Acme/*/*.php
do
sed '/^$/d' $file > tt
mv tt $file
done
```

`It says Demo is a directory`

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
for fname in `find /home/zubinan/public_html/src/Acme/ -type f`
do
    sed '/^$/d' $fname > tt
    mv tt $fname
done
```

Comment: I am trying that but how can only specify .php files

Comment: @user1596900, instead of `-type f` use `-name "*.php"`

Comment: You can use both, to protect against the (exceedingly unlikely) event that there is a directory that matches "*.php".

Answer (score 0):

If you want process all specified files in some directory, you can use this oneliner:

```
sed -i '/^$/d' `find /home/zubinan/public_html/src/Acme -name "*.php"`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in $(find /home/zubinan/public_html/src/Acme -type f \( -iname *.php \)); 
    do 
        relfilePath=${f:${#currentpath}:${#f}};
        // use  relfilePath here

    done
```

Answer (score 0):

or try this:

```
 find /home/zubinan/public_html/src/Acme/ -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -e '/^$/d' -i \{\} \;
```